# Horizontal lines are not displaying in proper position between text in a site

Tags: html, css

Here you can see " TOP OFFERS", "TOP Category", "featured products", " Top categories" , "TOP brands",

But you can see text "TOP brands" , it's not in between 2 lines, but that line is displaying below " TOP categories

images". I want to move that line near top brands as like other sections.

Please help me to find solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add margin top to horizontal line. If you add screen shots will be better for  us to understand.

Comment: Which browser ru checking? I checked in FF37 and Chrome 40, everything is fine apart from that 'Featured Categories' is glued to the lines on both the sides

Comment: @CodeLord  i will post screen shot soon......

Comment: @profile15 is the below answer which you want

Comment: @Pawan those lines under " top categories is problem"

Comment: You should include the relevant code within your question, so it is helpful for others in the future.

Comment: @KawineshSK i am working on that one , just a minute....

Comment: @KawineshSK  please check once again, are you sure it's working fine, but in aniother system also same problem is there.....

Comment: @profile15 can u see my comment and answer

Comment: @KawineshSK please check here : http://prntscr.com/6z1bf3

Comment: it's fine now, i am really sorry for wasted your time.... it's working in another systems.....

Comment: @profile15 sorry i dont see that issue at all in your site

Comment: @ Kawainesh , CodeLord , pawan , alfonso please help me to make this site responsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class=" grid_25">
  <br><br>
<div class="horizontal_line">
<div><span>TOP BRANDS</span></div>
</div>
<br><br> <a href="shop-by-brand/fisher-price.html"> <img class="fluid51" style="max-width: 31.6%;" src="brand1.jpg" alt=""> </a> 
<a href="shop-by-brand/funskool.html"><img class="fluid52" style="max-width: 31.6%;" src="brand6.jpg" alt=""> </a> 
<a href="shop-by-brand/masoom.html"><img class="fluid53" style="max-width: 31.6%;" src="brand7.jpg" alt=""> </a> <br> 
<a href="shop-by-brand/zephyr.html"> <img class="fluid54" style="max-width: 31.6%;" src="brand4.jpg" alt=""> </a> 
<a href="shop-by-brand/peacock.html"><img class="fluid55" style="max-width: 31.6%;" src="brand8.jpg" alt=""> </a> 
<a href="shop-by-brand/ekta.html"><img class="fluid56" style="max-width: 31.6%;" src="brand9.jpg" alt=""> </a>
</div>
```

> The Problem was in every `grid_25` and `grid_24` you have mentioned two
>   line breaks via `<br>` which gave you the look as you wanted and u
>   have forgot to mention it in the `grid_25` which i added in the html
>   by inspect elemeent and below is how your page looks.

Comment: i did what you told, but it's not reflecting on site?

Comment: @profile15 if you face the same issue can u upload the photo of your screen in http://imgur.com/ and paste the link in the comment

Comment: please delete the images that you added in answer.

Comment: thanks a lot , is it possible for you to replace real site name  by www.sitename.com